# Получить JSON ответ

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, json, curl

Работаю с API Yandex.

Получаю ответ в формате JSON.

На JS проблем нет:

```
$.ajax({
   url: "https://api-metrika.yandex.ru/stat/sources/phrases.json",
   data: {
      id: "значение id",
      pretty: "1",
      oauth_token: "Значение ключа"
   },
   dataType: "jsonp",
   success: function(data) {
      var str = "";
      var len = data.data.length

      for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
         str += data.data[i].visit_time + ", ";

      }
      $("div").html(str);

   }
});
```

Но в целях безопасности (не хочу светить `id` и `token`), хочу получить файл через `curl`, а затем просто результат послать в ответ AJAX и работать как я работал выше в результатом AJAX. То есть парсить все JS

Comment: ну так сделайте просто запрос к контроллеру на пхп, который и сделает запрос к метрике и вернет вам файл.

Comment: Что то с этим и возникли проблемы.Бред какой то получается с  curl у меня. Можете примерно показать ,в какую сторону "копать"

Comment: скажите, какие дыры в безопасности вы латаете таким решением?

Comment: так можно просмотреть токен и id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

php

```
if( $curl = curl_init() ) { 
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api-metrika.yandex.ru/stat/sources/phrases.json"); 
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    // данные, которые отправляются
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "id=test_id&pretty=1&oauth_token=test_oauth_token"); 
    $out = curl_exec($curl);
    echo $out;
    curl_close($curl);
}
```

js

```
$.ajax({
  url:"metrika.php",
  dataType: "jsonp",
  success: function (data) {
      console.log(data)
  },
  error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
     console.log(xhr.status);
     console.log(thrownError);
  }
});
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54034/discussion-on-answer-by-kudraem--json-).